# Deep learning word2vec for small text

Tags: nlp, text-mining, word2vec

I am using word2vec from R [here][1]

My data come from a csv file. Following are the data I have:

```
net
abap
access
account management
accounting
active directory
agile methodologies
agile project management
ajax
algorithms
analysis
android
android development
angularjs
ant
apache
asp
asp net
banking
bb
bpmn
budgets
business analysis
business development
business intelligence
business planning
business process
business process design
business strategy
c
change management
channel partners
cisco technologies
cloud computing
cms
competitive analysis
computer hardware
computer science
consulting
contract negotiation
corporate communications
crm
css
customer service
cvs
data analysis
data center
data migration
data warehousing
database design
databases
db
design patterns
direct sales
drupal
eclipse
ecommerce
economics
editing
ejb
english
enterprise architecture
enterprise software
erp
european union
event management
finance
financial analysis
firewalls
forecasting
french
git
hardware
help desk support
hibernate
html
human resources
iis
incident management
integration
it management
it service management
it strategy
itil
java
java enterprise edition
javascript
jboss application server
jdbc
jee
jira
jms
joomla
jpa
jquery
jsf
json
jsp
junit
key account management
leadership
linux
management
management consulting
market research
marketing
marketing communications
marketing strategy
matlab
maven
microsoft excel
microsoft exchange
microsoft office
microsoft sql server
microsoft word
mobile applications
mobile devices
ms project
mysql
negotiation
netbeans
network administration
network security
networking
new business development
object oriented design
oop
operating systems
oracle
oracle applications
oracle sql
outsourcing
photoshop
php
plsql
pmo
pmp
postgresql
powerpoint
presales
problem solving
product development
product management
product marketing
program management
programming
project management
project planning
project portfolio
public relations
public speaking
python
quality assurance
requirements analysis
requirements gathering
research
rest
retail
risk management
rup
saas
sales
sales management
sales operations
sap
sap erp
sap r
scrum
security
selenium
seo
servers
servlets
sharepoint
shell scripting
soa
soap
social media
social media marketing
social networking
software design
software development
software documentation
software engineering
software installation
software project
software quality
solution architecture
solution selling
spring
spring framework
spss
sql
sql server
startups
strategic planning
strategy
struts
subversion
system administration
systems analysis
tcpip
teaching
team building
team leadership
team management
teamwork
technical support
telecommunications
testing
tomcat
training
troubleshooting
tsql
uml
unix
unix shell scripting
user acceptance testing
vb net
virtualization
visio
visual basic
visual studio
vmware
voip
vpn
web applications
web design
web development
web services
weblogic
windows
windows server
wordpress
xml
xslt
```

I would like to extract cluster of text so I could categorize the words. I use the following code from word2vec.

```
library(wordVectors)
model = train_word2vec("C:/Users/Desktop/input.csv",output="C:/Users/Desktop/output.vectors",threads = 3,vectors = 100,window=12)
nearest_to(model,model[["bussiness"]])
```

I would expect to see nearest words based on bussiness because from observation of input file I can see that there are exist but I only take NA from output of nearest_to

```
> nearest_to(model,model[["bussiness"]])
<NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> 
  NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA
```

What can I do to fix the problem in code?
      [1]: https://github.com/bmschmidt/wordVectors

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the definitions of parameters you are passing. Window = 12, while your lines are maximum 2 words doesn't make sense. In general, you wouldn't get anything out of word2vec by using this much text you provided here. You need a metric & resource that doesn't rely on co-occurrences. Use [WordNet](http://wordnet), [Roget's Thesaurus](http://www.nzdl.org/ELKB/). Have a look at [this](http://spectrum.library.concordia.ca/977146/1/Shareghi-Nojehdeh_MCompSc_S2013.pdf) (may be useful...).